How to insert one blank page after every current page in the [limited area] of document?
Setup
Windows11; TeXLive2024; WinEdt11; PDFLaTeX.
The statement of my problem
I intended to apply this method to insert one blank page after every current page of document partially(locally).
As is noted, I wrote a block based on a conditional variable \ifstophook to decide the time to run or stop the function of atbegshi package.
\newif\ifstophooks 
\global\stophooksfalse
\AtBeginShipoutNext{
  \AtBeginShipout{%
    \ifstophooks
      % no actions
    \else
      \AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\null
    \fi
  }%
}

However, it didn't stop in the right position. For instance, by using the following notation:

N: non-blank page
B: blank page(, which is generated by commands of atbegshi package)

the ideal output(, which is what I wanted as well) should be NNN[block to run]NBNB[block to stop]NNN, whereas the result was NNN[block to run]BNBN[block to stop]NNN, that is, one extra blank page was added in the beginning of central area and was lacked at the end of that.
I didn't know what's going on and how to fix it. Any explanation or solution is appreciated.
MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifstophooks
\global\stophooksfalse
\AtBeginShipoutNext{
  \AtBeginShipout{%
    \ifstophooks
      % no actions
    \else
      \AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\null
    \fi
  }%
}


\begin{document}

% no need to insert blank pages
\global\stophookstrue
\lipsum
\lipsum
\clearpage

% start inserting pages
\global\stophooksfalse
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{abstract}
\clearpage

% stop inserting pages
\global\stophookstrue
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{The Second Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{abstract}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX!

I think you are overcomplicating things. Also be aware that atbegshi is obsolete, in a current latex it is replaced by a version that uses the LaTeX hooks described in ltshipout-doc.pdf
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifstophooks
\global\stophooksfalse
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{%
    \ifstophooks
      % no actions
    \else
      \RawShipout\null
    \fi}


\begin{document}

% no need to insert blank pages
\stophookstrue
\lipsum
\lipsum
\clearpage

% start inserting pages
\stophooksfalse
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{abstract}
\clearpage

% stop inserting pages
\stophookstrue
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{The Second Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{abstract}

\end{document}


Thanks a lot. It indeed works!
